# Can a Git Repository Branch be a sub folder in some other Git Repository?

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-mvc, github

Can a Git Repository Branch be a sub folder in some other Git Repository?

What I mean by this is if I am working in a git repository called "webdesign" and it has a branch called "JSP" can I somehow map a folder in my "project-a" repository to add the branchs.

I would like to do this so a my web designer can work in his Git Repository and as I am coding my project use his JSP pages.

Answer (score 4):

For what you want there are `git submodules` - http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Basically, your designers can work in their own repo and that repo is added as a submodule ( which will be in a sub-folder like you want ) to the main repo.